# Get wrong date and time with high_resolution_clock in Visual Studio 2017 / Get number of milliseconds from epoch time (1 jan 1970)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, time

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2017.

I'm trying to get the current time and date with millisecond resolution. I tried the follwing code in a few compilers:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main()
{

    high_resolution_clock::time_point p = high_resolution_clock::now();
    milliseconds ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(p.time_since_epoch());
    seconds s = duration_cast<seconds>(ms);
    time_t t = s.count();
    cout << ctime(&t) << "\n";
    cin.ignore(1);
}
```

Every compiler except Visual Studio 2017 prints the correct time. The output of Visual Studio is:

> > Tue Jan  6 07:28:21 1970

the MinGW Output:

> > Sun Feb 03 18:01:38 2019

Is there any way to fix the code so that it works in all compilers correctly? I need high_resolution_clock to have access to milliseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[high_resolution_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) is an alias for the clock with the highest resoultion availavle:

> Class std::chrono::high_resolution_clock represents the clock with the smallest tick period provided by the implementation. It may be an alias of std::chrono::system_clock or std::chrono::steady_clock, or a third, independent clock.

This could explain the different times you get on different compilers.

[steady_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) Does not guarantee to give a time that makes sense, but is good for keeping track time:

> This clock is not related to wall clock time (for example, it can be time since last reboot), and is most suitable for measuring intervals.
> Is there any way to fix the code so that it works in all compilers correctly? I need high_resolution_clock to have access to milliseconds.

[system_clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock) represents the clock of your OS:

> Class std::chrono::system_clock represents the system-wide real time wall clock.
>
> It may not be monotonic: on most systems, the system time can be adjusted at any moment. It is the only C++ clock that has the ability to map its time points to C-style time, and, therefore, to be displayed (until C++20).

If you need the milliseconds of a date or timepoint then use std::chrono::system_clock but if you just need to keep track of passed time, use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock.

To get the number of milliseconds since the start of system_clock:

```
auto timePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
                                    (timePoint.time_since_epoch());
std::cout << "since epoch: " << ms.count() << " ms";
```

above snippet should work across most operating systems and compilers, although it is not guaranteed that time_since_epoch returns the time since 1970 but only to return the time since the clocks epoch, which in most cases is your desired behaviour.

Comment: Does the specification somewhere say that `time_since_epoch` returns the duration since Jan 1 1970? Most implementation probably do. But is it guaranteed?

Comment: That is true, It is not guaranteed that std::system_clock has the same epch as unix. I edited my answer.

Comment: The draft C++20 spec currently adds the requirement that `system_clock` measure against the 1970 epoch.

Answer (score 1):

The code assumes that `time_since_epoch()` returns the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 – so the value would be assignable to a variable `time_t`.

That assumption is wrong. `time_since_epoch()` can return any unit. In fact, `high_resolution_clock` is not designed to retrieve an absolute time and date. It's meant for performance measurements in the micro and nano seconds range.

In order to retrieve an absolute time / date, use `system_clock`. The class has a static method to create a `time_t` value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main()
{
    time_point<system_clock> now = system_clock::now();
    time_t now_time = system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    cout << ctime(&now_time) << "\n"
}
```

**Update**

To get the milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main()
{
    system_clock::time_point epochStart = system_clock::from_time_t(0);
    long long epochStartMs = duration_cast<milliseconds>(epochStart.time_since_epoch()).count();

    system_clock::time_point timePoint = system_clock::now();
    long long timePointMs = duration_cast<milliseconds>(timePoint.time_since_epoch()).count();

    long long durMs = timePointMs - epochStartMs;

    cout << "Since 1st Jan 1970: " << durMs << " ms" << "\n";
}
```

For most systems, `epochStartMs` will probably be 0. But I think the standard doesn't guarantee that `system_clock` has it's epoch start on Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: How about the milliseconds then? How can I get them?

Comment: Are you just interested in milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970? Or in a formatted date with millisecond resolution?

Comment: I'm interested in number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. And I hope I can have a multi-platform code.